# Ubuntu Wi-Fi Auth trouble

Tags: networking, password

My network got a password recently, which i know and am willing to enter, obviously.
But when i try to connect, i get a message that says " Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the Wi-Fi network 'MyNetworkName' "
In that same window i also get a "Cancel" button, and a greyed out "Connect" button.
And no place to enter a password for some reason.
I've tried to go into Edit Networks, finding my network there, and entering the password, which changed absolutely nothing, the pop-up window stays exactly the same.
My question is: Why does this happen? what is the cause? I thought ubuntu was smart. (I'm on 16.04 btw)

EDIT: The problem fixed itself when i upgraded to 18.04. It asked for the password like it should.

Comment: How many characters is the password? You won't be offered the option to connect unless the WPA password is 8-63 characters long.

Comment: Its 10 characters, with no weird symbols or anything.